# Is it technically possible to transfer ownership of vested tokens?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation

I am stuck with a vested crypto bag. A acquitance of mine would like to have my bag. Is there a way do to it properly ? Like creating  dVested token or synthetic one. In order to be registered on the blockchain and as soon as released he will automatically own it. If so, which way would be better ?

Comment: It depends on the token and the vesting contract.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what way you "own" this particular crypto bag.

1. If your account owns the vested tokens, and the vested token contract allows you to transfer ownership, then you should be able to simply execute a method to transfer the vested tokens to your friend's account.
2. You could create a smart contract and give permission to transfer your vested tokens only to another address once your friend invokes a method, however, I can't see how this is better than no. 1.
3. If your account owns the vested tokens but the vested token contract does not allow you to transfer the ownership then you might be able to give access to the account (as long as you move other tokens you might own elsewhere), however, **this would mean that now 2 people have access to the same account. It's not necessarily a good idea but it's up to the two of you as long as you have a mutual agreement.**

*Note: I could better answer if you elaborate on your question.*

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer !

In my particular case I entered in early stage and I guess my tokens are on "team contract" and I will get them at release time. 

For that case is there any way to ensure through the blockchains that it will automatically go to another user ? And if somehow I succeed through a "synthetic token" to directly transfer it,  would it be consider as secondary market ?